# How to set CardView's elevation programmatically?

Tags: android, android-cardview

Hello I just want to set the elevation of cardview programmatically but seems it does not work , here's my Code :

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    cardView.setLayoutParams(params);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
    cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    cardView.setCardElevation(1000);
    linearLayout.addView(cardView);
```

even though setCardEleveation is set to 1000 there is no changes to cardview, what's wrong ? 
there is some related question out there but i can't got the answer.

Comment: Which android version are you using ?  If u are using pre lollipop card elevation won't work.

Comment: my least api version is 15 , so there is no compatible library for ? @HimanshuKohli

Comment: posted the answer below check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok , i had a tricky problem , my Cardview wrapped its Parent up so there is no space available to show its shadow. finally I added margin to the Cardview and now It works !!

Answer (score 0):

use `cardview.setMaxCardElevation(8);` instead

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#setMaxCardElevation(float) check this, remove the `setCardElevation`

Answer (score 0):

From elevation depends only views shadow. It is good shown when elevation is about `2`, `10`, may be `20` and not much more. When you set something like `1000` shadow becomes almost invisible because of great distance (as it is in the real world :) ).

Try to set less elevation.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum api is 15 and max is 21

[Image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAPzz.png)

```
CardView cardView = new CardView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params =
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200);
        cardView.setLayoutParams(params);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        cardView.setCardElevation(20);
        linearLayout.addView(cardView);
```

Answer (score -1):

XML property "cardElevation" will achieve this for you, however. Since the Material Design Guideline states that the CardView elevation can only be 8dp, you can as well set this in your XML file once and for all.